# useradd from jenkins user error: useradd: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later

Tags: linux, permissions, bash, useradd

I run a shell script (Centos 6.7)  from jenkins containing this command, in order import root environment:

```
 env -i `cat /home/admin/root_environment.sh` /home/admin/create_user.sh
```

The root_environment was generated with

```
 env > root_environment.sh
```

the script create_user.sh contains

```
/usr/sbin/useradd -p "pass" "username"
```

Jenkins is running with its own jenkins user.
The script create_user.sh is working correctly if I run it as root, however, running from jenkins I get:

```
 useradd: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add user jenkins to the wheel group with sudo privileges (as root)

```
usermod -aG wheel jenkins
```

and then use this in your script

```
echo "jenkins-password" | sudo -S /usr/sbin/useradd -p "pass" "username"
```